# Is there any way to create unique dictionary attribute for every instance in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Using a class to create several instances in a dictionary, their attribute is not unique.  I'd like each of them to have their own unique attribute.  How do you do this?

code:

```
class a(object):

    attr_a = {}

    def __init__(self, a={}):

        self.attr_a = a

if __name__ == '__main__':

    b = a()
    c = a()
    b.attr_a['abc'] = 'abc'
    c.attr_a['abc'] = 'def'

    print(b.attr_a)
    print(c.attr_a)
```

result:

```
{'abc': 'def'}
{'abc': 'def'}
```

wanted result:

```
{'abc': 'abc'}
{'abc': 'def'}
```

Comment: You have a dict instead of a `list`, but ultimately, the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: @mgilson:thx,i know how it works in function level,but doubt about class level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

1) For instance-level attributes, as opposed to class-level attributes, don't declare at the class level. So, remove the `attr_a = {}` in your class.

2) The default value `a={}` is evaluated at class/function declaration time, as opposed to instance-creation/function-call time, so rarely should you use a mutable object as a default value. This causes all instances of your class that are created with the default `a` value to share the same `attr_a` dict. You should use `a=None` as your default value, and then instantiate it inside of `__init__` instead, like this:

```
def __init__(self, a=None):
        self.attr_a = a or {}
```

Comment: Don't use `a or {}`.  What if someone passed in a reference to an empty dict or any other falsy value?  It's much better to avoid laziness and do:  `self.attr_a = {} if a is None else a`. (and document the fact that `None` is the sentinel value you're using).

Comment: @mgilson:thx, somebody suggest:`if not a: a = {}; self.attr_a = {}`

Comment: @mgilson, point taken!